# Changing li height using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My html like

```
<div id="listview">
    <ul>
    <li style="height: 373px;">
    </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

here the li have style added dynamically.I need to change the height of the li using jquery.I tried some code but not works

anybody help...

Comment: your code works as expected when using append()... http://jsfiddle.net/TbEzC/

Comment: This is really not a serious question...

Comment: perhaps you should read the jquery documentation and find out what the functions actually do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
$("#listview > ul > li").css('height','200px');
```

`append` function is used to add a child DOM element to an object no to add attributes

if you want to add an attributes similar to the way you did you can do the following

```
$("#listview > ul > li").attr('style','height: 200px;');
```

and the best way to change the height is by height function

```
$("#listview > ul > li").height('200px');
```

Comment: I'm Glad that i could help

Answer (score 3):

Read doc:

```
$("#listview > ul > li").height(200);
```

Answer (score 3):

You use this:-

```
$("#listview > ul > li").height(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("#listview  ul  li").css({"height": "200px"});
```

or

```
$("#listview  ul  li").css("height", "200px");
```

Comment: BTW, your are changing selector which could be not what OP is expecting

Comment: Still incorrect. You need to either replace the colon with a comma, or wrap the CSS in braces.

Answer (score 1):

`append` function will append his parameter into html. Use `css`:

`$("#listview > ul > li").css('height','200px');`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#listview > ul > li").css('height', '200px');
```